# Dragged item ui issue with react using react-sortable-hoc

Tags: reactjs, vite

I'm using drag and drop with react-sortable-hoc when i use drag and drop functionality i'm able to do , but after i close the drog and drop container pop up what ever the fields i dragged those are coming on top of the UI .

I have been trying to resolve it but i'm not able to .

Could anyone please help me with this ?

below is the code for ref

`.sortableHelper {   z-index: 2000; }`

```
import { Shimmer } from 'components/Shimmer';
import { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';
import { SortableContainer, SortableElement } from 'react-sortable-hoc';
import './ImageEditor.css';

const CELL_BORDER_RADIUS = 6;
const CELL_DIM = '12vh';
const INNER_BOX_WIDTH = '3vh';

const SortableItem = SortableElement(
  ({ item, indexNum, onClickCell, isCurrentImage }) => {
    //   const intl = useIntl();
    const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);
    const imageRef = useRef();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    const renderNumber = (indexNum) => {
      return (
        <span
          style={{
            background: 'white',
            display: 'flex',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            height: INNER_BOX_WIDTH,
            width: INNER_BOX_WIDTH,
            borderRadius: '50%',
            margin: '0.6vh',
            fontSize: '0.7rem',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}>
          {indexNum}
        </span>
      );
    };

    const renderBottomTag = (tagName) => {
      return (
        <div
          style={{
            display: 'flex',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            height: '4vh',
            width: CELL_DIM,
            padding: '0.1rem',
          }}>
          <span style={{ fontSize: '0.7rem', lineHeight: 'normal' }}>
            {tagName}
          </span>
        </div>
      );
    };

    const handleOnLoad = function handleOnLoad() {
      setLoading(false);
    };

    const renderShimmer = () => {
      return (
        <div
          style={
            loading
              ? {
                  width: CELL_DIM,
                  height: CELL_DIM,
                  position: 'absolute',
                  background: 'red',
                  borderRadius: CELL_BORDER_RADIUS,
                }
              : { display: 'none' }
          }>
          <Shimmer
            style={{
              width: '100%',
              height: '100%',
              borderRadius: CELL_BORDER_RADIUS,
            }}
          />
        </div>
      );
    };

    const renderURL = `${import.meta.env.REACT_APP_DIRECTUS}assets/${
      item.directus_files_id || item?.file
    }`;
    return (
      <>
        <div
          className="sortableHelper"
          onClick={() => {
            onClickCell(item);
          }}
          onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}
          onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}
          style={{
            margin: '0.5vh',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            listStyleType: 'none',
            display: 'inline-block',
            width: CELL_DIM,
            borderRadius: CELL_BORDER_RADIUS,
            height: CELL_DIM,
            boxShadow: isCurrentImage ? '0 0 0 2pt black' : '0 0 0 0',
          }}>
          {renderShimmer()}
          <div
            style={{
              display: 'flex',
              flexDirection: 'column',
              justifyContent: 'space-between',
              width: CELL_DIM,
              height: CELL_DIM,
              position: 'absolute',
            }}>
            <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
              {renderNumber(indexNum)}
            </div>

            <div
              style={{
                borderBottomRightRadius: 6,
                borderBottomLeftRadius: 6,
                width: CELL_DIM,
                background: hover ? 'white' : 'rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.7)',
                color: hover ? 'black' : 'white',

                display: 'flex',
                justifyContent: 'center',
              }}>
              {indexNum === 1 &&
                renderBottomTag(
                  !hover ? (
                    <FormattedMessage id={'image.main'} />
                  ) : (
                    <FormattedMessage
                      id={'image.dragToRearrange'}
                    />
                  )
                )}
              {indexNum === 2 &&
                renderBottomTag(
                  !hover ? (
                    <FormattedMessage id={'upload.image.secondary'} />
                  ) : (
                    <FormattedMessage
                      id={'upload.image.dragToRearrange'}
                    />
                  )
                )}
              {indexNum > 2 &&
                hover &&
                renderBottomTag(
                  <FormattedMessage
                    id={'upload.image.dragToRearrange'}
                  />
                )}
            </div>
          </div>
          <img
            ref={imageRef}
            alt="prodcuts"
            width={'100%'}
            style={
              loading
                ? { visibility: 'hidden', height: CELL_DIM }
                : { borderRadius: 6, height: '12vh' }
            }
            src={renderURL}
            onLoad={handleOnLoad}
          />
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
);

export const SortableList = SortableContainer(
  ({ items, onClickCell, currentImage }) => {
    return (
      <div>
        {items.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <>
              <SortableItem
                key={`item-${item.uid}`}
                index={index}
                indexNum={index + 1}
                item={item}
                onClickCell={onClickCell}
                isCurrentImage={currentImage === item?.directus_files_id}
              />
            </>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwskU.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgGT7.png)